# Project Link Error after adding class

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm writing a 3D image engine (it reads a XML with a scene info and it prints with openGL) for college, in visual studio (unfortunately...), and I'm doing the parser atm, which reads the xml into a simple tree-like data structure. One of the elements is Camera and before i added that part of the data structure, the program was running ok, but after i added it, i'm having the following errors:

```
1>LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(_fpinit_.obj) : error LNK2005: __fltused already defined in a previous module
1>LIBCMT.lib(_fpinit_.obj) : error LNK2005: __ldused already defined in a previous module
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: _isalpha already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: _isspace already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: _isalnum already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj) : error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(atox.obj) : error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(tolower.obj) : error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(strtol.obj) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>bin\CGFexample.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I can't understand why adding a simple new class would create such a weird error, can anyone help?

P.S. Ill add the camera class if needed but its really just a bunch of variables with sets and gets and two child classes (there's two types of cameras), and I don't think the problem is because of the class itself anyway.

Comment: Are you using any `#pragma` statements in the newly added files? Are you sure you didn't change any linker settings or added additional libraries?

Comment: As you can see the error is that you are linking with both LIBCMT.lib and MSVCRTD.lib, you should be linking with one or other of these libraries not both. There are many ways you can get this conflict and it's difficult to tell what you've done wrong from this distance. I suggest recreating your project from scratch and paying careful consideration to the linker and compiler options you pick. And if your code contains any `#pragma comment (lib, ...` directives I would remove them.

Comment: I dont even know what #pragma statements are so i doubt i used them... ill try recreating the project...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentionned by @John, you should use either dynamic or static C run time linking. In Visual Studio, this is controlled by  `RunTime Library property` (C/C++ folder > Code Generation > Runtime Library property). You have 4 options for the C run time : debug/release & static/dynamic.

**Side note**: If you are using a 3rd party dll, a manifest file should give you some info about the run time being used. You can double check it using tools like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (In case of dynamic, you will see a dll named MSVCRXXX.DLL) with XXX the version of VC and D for Debug

Answer (score 5):

I resolved your specific problem ignoring one of those libs.

For that go to (`Project Properties->Linker->Input->Ignore Specific Default Libraries`) and enter `LIBCMT.lib`